# Unresolved external symbol "public: class Foo __thiscall Bar::bu(char const *)"

Tags: c++, class, unresolved-external

Here's what I've got.  I'm trying to create an instance of Foo within in Bar, using a custom constructor.  When I try to call the constructor from Bar's constructor I get and unresolved external.

```
class Foo
{
public:
    // The custom constructor I want to use.
    Foo(const char*);
};

class Bar
{
public:
    Bar();
    //The instance of Foo I want to use being declared.
    Foo bu(const char*);
};

int main(int argc, char* args[])
{
    return 0;
}

Bar::Bar()
{
    //Trying to call Foo bu's constructor.
    bu("dasf");
}

Foo::Foo(const char* iLoc)
{
}
```

Comment: That code isn't valid. When you add a member variable you do it as a pointer when you want to use a custom contructor: Foo *bu; Then create the instance in the constructor.

Comment: It's rather a linker problem. I think the source you posted is not enough to solve your problem here. Is everything declared in the same translation unit (file)? Then I think it should work. If not, you should edit the source indicating what is stored in which file and give full compiler and linker command lines with the corresponding output (shouldn't be that much in this case).

Comment: @peterept: I think it's valid, just that Bar::bu is declared as a method returning a Foo and not a member variable. In Bar::Bar() the bu method gets called, returning an object that isn't used. Doesn't make much sense, but should work.

Comment: @Axel  It is all in one file.  The pasted example is what I'm using to get the error, nothing more and nothing less.  I don't understand why it won't work

Comment: Sorry, I read it to quickly. You are just missing the implementation of Foo bu(const char*) function. It's not listed in the sample above. You declared it, but didn't provide it's implementation. If you meant  bu to be an object, then what I said above is correct. Just have Foo *bu be the member and allocate it.

Comment: peterept: it's so obvious that noone has seen it before... of course you are right :-)

Comment: question: according to what you want to achieve, is bu "a method that returns Foo instance" or 'a member of class Bar that's of type Foo"?

Comment: Thanks peter, that did it.  Now in the class destructor I'm going to need to delete that allocated memory right?  How would I do this?                                                                  @Lele, it's a member of Bar of type Foo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably what you want:

```
class Foo
{
public:
    // The custom constructor I want to use.
    Foo(const char*);
};

class Bar
{
public:
    Bar();
   //The instance of Foo I want to use being declared.
   Foo bu; // Member of type Foo
};

int main(int argc, char* args[])
{
    return 0;
}

Bar::Bar() : bu("dasf") // Create instance of type Foo
{
}

Foo::Foo(const char* iLoc)
{
}
```

As for this declaration: `Foo bu(const char*);` This is a declaration of a member function named `bu` which takes a `const char*` and returns a `Foo`. The unresolved symbol error is because you never defined the function `bu`, but you want an instance of `Foo` not a function.

Other method after seeing comments:

```
class Foo
{
public:
    // The custom constructor I want to use.
    Foo(const char*);
};

class Bar
{
public:
    Bar();
    ~Bar() { delete bu;} // Delete bu
   //The instance of Foo I want to use being declared.
   Foo *bu; // Member of type Foo
};

int main(int argc, char* args[])
{
    return 0;
}

Bar::Bar() : bu(new Foo("dasf")) // Create instance of type Foo
{
}

Foo::Foo(const char* iLoc)
{
}
```

And there are also many other problems with your code, maybe getting a book on C++ like [C++ Primer](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201721481) would be a good idea.